# Knockoutjs ObservableArray ArrayFilter on multiple columns

Tags: knockout-3.0

I am trying to filter an ObservableArray through multiple columns.

My problem is similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26374056/knockout-filtering-objects-in-observable-arrays-by-multiple-object-properties) but my model differs since each entry in an observable array is an object of observables.

```
var Employee = function(name, job, state, phone)
{
    this.name = ko.observable(name);
    this.job = ko.observable(job);
    this.state = ko.observable(state);
    this.phone = ko.observable(phone);
};

self.employees = ko.observableArray([
    new Employee("Sarah","Manager","","123456"),
    new Employee("Michelle","Receptionist","California",""),
    new Employee("James","","Florida","1213123"),
    new Employee("Steve","","Team Lead",""),
    new Employee("Britney","","Developer","")
]);
```

My array is presented as a table and will have a feature for the user to filter each column for empty values.

I am dealing with a dynamic list of columns to filter (taken from an observablearray too)

```
self.rowheader = ko.observableArray(["Name","Job","State","Phone" ]);
```

I can't seem to figure out how map these values and evaluate these to a condition using ko.utils.arrayFilter

Here's a [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/jinxed_coder/0n664g9p/) of where I am at the moment.
Appreciate your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to find a solution for this but I'm still hoping somebody could suggest a more elegant solution to this.

I have to dynamically construct the return condition of the arrayFilter function based on the selectedColumns content. The filteredArray observable now looks like this:

```
self.filteredemployees = ko.computed(function() {
    if(self.selectedColumns().length) {
        return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.employees(), function(emp) {
            var filter = ko.utils.arrayMap(self.selectedColumns(), function(item) {
                            return 'emp.' + item.toLowerCase() + '() === ""';
                        }).join(' && ');

            return eval(filter)
        });
    } else {
        return self.employees();
    }
}, self);
```

I got no choice but to do an eval there.